# Beamer: Index of Listing

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, indexing

In beamer presentation I have a few headwords distributed on different slides. The appearance of these headwords I defined before and they don't be numbered.

Before these headwords started, I want to insert an overview/index of them on an extra slide and there should be the headwords numbered (but it's not so important, only listed without numbers would be also ok). I have no idea how to realize them -- I tried a bit with `label` but it don't works.

Currenty I realize this, while copy the headwords on the index-slide in an enumerate environment. This is not very elegant.

I hope I could make understandable the issue. And btw: How I declare a codeblock here? Four spaces at begin of every line -- it's a bit troublesome for longer codeblocks.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{Title}

\newcommand{\hervor}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{This should be the index}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Blah blah
  \item Foo bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Theorys}
\hervor{Blah blah}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Theorys}
\lipsum
\hervor{Foo bar}
\lipsum

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the headwords be separated by section or something? To mark code block you can use the button `{}`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56417/list-of-figures-beamer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible basic solution; the idea is to use the kernel `\@starttoc` command to generate a new "List of" with `.lof` extension. The `\hervor` command now typesets its argument in the document and also adds the information for the new list to the `.loh` file. The list is generated by issuing `\listofhervors`:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcounter{hervor}

% this commands typesets the text in the document with the given format
% and also adds it to the .loh file
\newcommand{\hervor}[1]{%
  \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
  \stepcounter{hervor}%
  \addcontentsline{loh}{section}{%
    \protect\makebox[1cm][l]{\protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{enumerate item}\thehervor.\hfill}#1\par}%
}

\newcommand{\lipsum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.}

% the command that will generate the new list
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofhervors{\@starttoc{loh}}
\makeatother

\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the index}
\listofhervors
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theorys}
\hervor{First relevant text}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theorys}
\lipsum\ \hervor{Second relevant text}\lipsum
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]