# Problem with missing spaces when having >9 subsections in table of contents (using the beamer class)

Tags: beamer, spacing, table-of-contents

I have googled extensively and found no answer to my specific question. My problem is: I am creating lecture slides using the `beamer` class. My style file is University-specific. I have, in my first `\section`, more than 9 `\subsections`. When I create the `\tableofcontents`, this looks like here:

[image: tableofcontents]

Notice that the subsections with number >9 have a missing (or, at least, not visible) space between the number and the name of the subsection (e.g.: 1.10Vibromyogramm (VMG)).

How can I prevent this and make my TOC more legible?

**EDIT1**

After following some initial answers, `\usepackage{tocloft}` is not the solution since it does not work with the `beamer` class (others have noticed that, too - see [List of Figures + Beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56417/list-of-figures-beamer)). Using `tocloft` causes pdflatex to fail with `!LaTeX Error: \l@section undefined` (it fails in the file `tocloft.sty` - and, as a previous poster said, lying to tocloft by defining the command as empty beforehand doesn't do any good either).

**EDIT2**

In reply to some comments by my fellow Latexers: If I only have, say, 3 `\subsections`, the spacing is exactly the same. Also, I do not think the reason is not only the style file; however, here is one line from the `beamer font theme` that is needed to understand the answer:

```
% Schriftart Helvetica
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Standard ist serifenlos
```

**EDIT3**

Thanks to Heiko's answer (see below), I have now found the solution to my problem. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It's quite hard to tell without knowing some details about the theme.

Comment: With only 9 sections is the spacing between the subsection number and the subsection name the same or different than it is currently?

Comment: I replied to your specific comments in the second edit above... I do not think it is the theme. In my google hunt, I have seen this problem quite some times, but w/o a satisfying solution. In a normal presentation, you would not have so many subsections, but in the specific case of a lecture... So maybe it is really the way that `beamer` creates the toc that is the problem. I just hate it. It does not look good.

Comment: The solution by Heiko below works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help! Most of the comments can be removed, if the admins would like that.

Answer (score 6):

This solution creates a new option `subsections numbered with max number` of template `subsection in toc` that takes a section number as argument that is used for the maximal width of the number.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% from beamerfontthemefau-4-3.sty
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Define a new option `subsections numbered with max number'
% for template `subsection in toc'. The original code for
% `subsections numbered' can be found in beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty:
%
% \defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{subsections numbered}{%
%   \leavevmode
%   \leftskip=2em%
%   \rlap{%
%     \hskip-2em%
%     \inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber
%   }%
%   \inserttocsubsection
%   \par
% }

\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{subsections numbered with max number}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \settowidth{\leftskip}{#1~}%
  \rlap{%
    \hskip-\leftskip
    \inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber~%
  }%
  \inserttocsubsection
  \par
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered with max number]{1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Test}
\addtocounter{subsection}{8}
\subsection{Ten}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heiko, your solution works perfectly. Thank you for your effort. I can not upvote, but I hope others will do.

Answer (score 2):

In `beamerbasetoc.sty` there is `\def\subsectionintoc{}` which appears to be responsible for setting subsections in the `toc`.  I haven't used beamer, so I don't know if there is a good reason not to do the following, or whether it will work for you, but try including the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter

\def\subsectionintoc{}
\long\def\beamer@subsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth>1%
  \ifnum#5=\beamer@showpartnumber%
  {
    \beamer@saveanother%
    \gdef\beamer@todo{}%
    \beamer@slideinframe=#1\relax%
    \expandafter\only\beamer@tocsections{\gdef\beamer@todo{%
      \ifbeamer@pausesubsections\pause\fi%
      \beamer@tempcount=#6%
      \advance\beamer@tempcount by\beamer@sectionadjust%
      \edef\inserttocsectionnumber{\the\beamer@tempcount}%
      \def\inserttocsubsectionnumber{#2}%
      %
      % the following line originally read
      % \def\inserttocsubsection{\hyperlink{Navigation#4}{#3}}%
      % you can add a skip before printing the subsection name
      %
      \def\inserttocsubsection{\hyperlink{Navigation#4}{\hskip 5pt #3}}% 
      \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=#1\beamer@toc@oss\else\beamer@toc@ooss\fi}%
      {%
        \def\beamer@breakhere{\\}%
        \beamer@tocact{\ifnum\c@section=#1\ifnum\c@subsection=#2\beamer@toc@css\else\beamer@toc@oss\fi\else\beamer@toc@ooss\fi}
        {subsection in toc}%
      }%
    }}%
    \beamer@restoreanother%
  }
  \beamer@todo%
  \fi\fi%
}

\makeatother
```

Alternatively, you might try to add the skip manually via.

```
\subsection{\unexpanded{\hskip 5pt}title}
```

or,

```
\subsection{\hskip 5pt title}
```

Both of which seem to work with what I have as a document.